# Javascript: Addition of Floating numbers gives incorrect precision

Tags: javascript

I add this floating numbers in javascript,
1403.07+1000.00
result is **2403.0699999999997**

It should be **2403.07**

I got a work around (1403.07+1000.00).toFixed(2), but this will fail if precision changes meaning; it will fail for addition of 1403.072+1000.01.

Is there any way I can achieve by jQuery/Javascipt, i dont need external library.

Comment: This might be a better duplicate: [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1458633/218196) ... anyways, if you search, you will find lots of questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = 2403.0699999999997;
result =   result.toFixed(2); //returns string fixed to 2 decimal places
result =   parseFloat(result);//returns double 2 decimal places
alert(result);
```

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/azT97/62/

Comment: Did you read the question?

Comment: using .toFixed(2) will be limited to 2 precisions.

for 1403.072+1000.01, result should be ** 2403.082 ** .
whereas, with .toFixed(2), would only give ** 2403.08 ** .